# Работа с файлами,Си

Tags: c

Есть код,который ищет ключевые слова си и выводит сколько раз он встретил их(в данном случае(for,while и т.д)Как можно сделать,чтоб он искал "for (),while()"
ps не важно как далеко будут стоять скобки=>"for(/////////-пробелы)"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int Search(char line[], char word[])
{
    char *p;
    int count = 0;
    //start = line;
        while(1){
            p = strstr(line, word);
            if(p == NULL)break;

            ++count;
            line = p + strlen(word);
        }
    return count;
}

int main(){

    int nf = 0, nw = 0, nd = 0, ni = 0;
    char s[100];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("f1.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(s, 100, fp)){
        nf += Search(s, "for");
        nw += Search(s, "while");
        nd += Search(s, "do");
        ni += Search(s, "if");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("V file f1 vstretilos:\n");
    printf("for %d raza \nwhile %d raza \ndo %d raza \nif %d raza\n", nf, nw, nd, ni);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а чем текущая реализация не нравится?

Comment: просто,если писать forwhat -он зачтет,хотя не нужно,первое приходит что на ум,поставить просто пробел,но дело как раз в этих скобках,между скобками может быть сколько угодно пробелов,гл.чтоб была закрывающейся,в нужном месте

Comment: ну я бы тогда просто пропускал все пробелы до `(` а потом все символы до `)` в цикле тупо.

Comment: @pavel вот как раз что-то туго с реализацией)

Comment: `bool findO = false;
for ( ;*p || !findO ; p++) findO = *p == '(';
if (!findO) return 0;
findO = false;
for ( ;*p || !findO ; p++) findO = *p == ')';
if (!findO) return 0;
return 1;` Идея дальше думаю оформите.

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Answer (score 2):

Задача, которую Вы описали (синтаксический анализ текста), на самом деле, довольно сложна. :-( Для полноценного распознавания синтаксических конструкций в текстовых файлах можно сгенерировать парсер с помощью lex/yac (flex/bison).

Сильно упростив задачу и наложив ограничение, что бы открывающая и закрывающая скобка всегда были на одной строке, можно воспользоваться

```
regex (3)            - POSIX regex functions
```

Простейший пример,  где это НЕ сработает:

```
for (j=0; j<23; // j++) {
```

Сложную задачу не решить просто - увы...